# Angular 5 : How to set Validation on two drop down list having same data?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

Data (json)

```
{
  "time": [
    "2017-1",
    "2017-2",
    "2017-3",
    "2017-4",
    "2017-5",
    ....
  ]
}
```

Template (Angular Material)

```
<mat-tab label="Recomandation Setting">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Select Year/Week" class="DropDownYear" multiple>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let time1 of resYearData.time" [value]="time1">{{time1}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select placeholder="Select Year/Week" class="DropDownYear" multiple>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resYearData.time" [value]="time2">{{time2}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)='toggle()'>View</button>
        </div>
      </div>
</mat-tab>
```

I'm Having two Drop down list contains same data with multiple selection, If i select on 2017-1, 2017-2(First drop-down)  then this value should not be selected/populated in second drop-down. I'm beginner to angular/Material what should i put validation here! I don't know what logic should i write in **HTML/Type-Script .**
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this... for example, just one way would be to split the arrays into two and splice the values from the second array when an option is selected in the first `mat-select`.

- You could also just disable the options in the second list when
  selected in the first `mat-select`... this will be the scenario I
  will use in this example.

Create component variable to store the selections from first `mat-select`

```
firstSelections: string = '';
```

Create method to set first selection values inside that variable

```
setFirstValues(values) {
    this.firstSelections = values;
  }
```

Then call that method on selection change from first `mat-select` and pass the values.

```
<mat-select #select1 placeholder="Select Year/Week" class="DropDownYear" multiple (selectionChange)="setFirstValues($event.value)">
```

Then in your second `mat-select` when defining the options use property binding on `disabled` to check if option is included in variable `firstSelections` to disable the option in second list if selected in the first.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resYearData.time" [value]="time2" [disabled]="firstSelections.includes(time2)">{{time2}}</mat-option>
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rc5vwq?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.html

---

If you require the options to physically be removed from the second list you will need to explore splitting `resYearData` into two separate arrays for each mat-select... and then remove the values from the second array on selection of first `mat-select`.

- The concept will be the same but rather than assigning the selection
  to a variable for comparison in disable, you would just remove the
  values from the second array in the `setFirstValues()` method.

---

**Per the comment made below by malbarmawi**

I have revised the stackblitz to address the issue if someone selects from second list first by removing the selection from the second list and then disabling.

Wrap the html in a template driven form, you can call it what ever you like, in this example I just call it myForm

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
```

Pass the form to your method on `selectionChange`

```
(selectionChange)="setFirstValues(myForm)"
```

Assign name and ngModel to each of the `mat-selects`

```
name="select1" ngModel
```

Get reference to second select via `ViewChild`

```
@ViewChild('select2') _select2: any
```

Set first selection values on change and splice value from second list if present and deselect.

```
setFirstValues(form) {
    this.firstSelections = form.value.select1
    const secondSelectionsValues = this._select2.value.slice();
    for (var i = 0; i < secondSelectionsValues.length; i++) {
      if (this.firstSelections.includes(secondSelectionsValues[i])) {
        secondSelectionsValues.splice(i, 1)
        this._select2.writeValue(secondSelectionsValues);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Revision**

Add null check to prevent logic from running if `this._select2.value` is not present.

```
setFirstValues(form) {
    this.firstSelections = form.value.select1
    if (this._select2.value) {
      const secondSelectionsValues = this._select2.value.slice();
      for (var i = secondSelectionsValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (this.firstSelections.includes(secondSelectionsValues[i])) {
          secondSelectionsValues.splice(i, 1)
          this._select2.writeValue(secondSelectionsValues);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what if I select second dropdown before first  

Comment: I think reactive form validation is better to handle all validation tasks

Comment: Then I would say that was not part of the original question :)

Comment: @Marshal you did a great job as you said `There are several ways to accomplish this` my answer is just another way

Comment: @malbarmawi please see revision to my answer and stackblitz on how to handle if you select from second dropdown before the first.

Comment: @Marshal sir, How to disable 2nd drop down list until and unless im select first drop down!?

Comment: @ShreeBatale please see revised stackblitz, you will need to add `[disabled]="!firstSelections || firstSelections == ''"` to your second select to disable it if no values are assigned to the `firstSelections` variable or it is an empty string.

Comment: @Marshal Thanks Sir,! ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined Im getting this error

Comment: I didn't understand @Marshal

Comment: review the component code in the stackblitz, you have `#select2` in your template, I am grabbing that in the component with `@ViewChild('select2') _select2: any` and then using that in this line `const secondSelectionsValues = this._select2.value.slice();`

Comment: Please revise your question to include your current code, or possibly provide a stackblitz so that I may debug.

Comment: i copied this code as it is ! its working Fine but when inspect this code .. it showing me error at console like   : Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined ........................const secondSelectionsValues = this._select2.value.slice();...................in ts....................<mat-select #select1 placeholder="Select Year/Week" class="DropDownYear" multiple (selectionChange)="setFirstValues(myForm)" .........in html

Comment: I see now, sorry for the confusion on my part, please see revision above, I also revised the stackblitz. I added a null check to make sure that `this._select2.value` is there before executing the logic.

Comment: @Marshal Thank You Sir :) Last One I'm Trying to disable my button until and unless i select 2nd drop down but I'm not getting that logic! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please raise a new question providing your current code, I or someone else will take a look.

Comment: Okay @Marshal sir,  Let me try my self else i will raised new Question Thank you So much Sir!

Comment: @Marshal Hi when i select 2nd drop down option that option would get disabled from drop down one! how?

Answer (score 2):

I do recommend use reactive form validation (FormGroup) it 'is more cleaner and you get the brnifetate to show validation error , disable save button base on form validation

*Component*

```
 form: FormGroup;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    let dropDownValueValidation = function (frm: FormGroup) {
      const firstValue: string[] = frm.get('first').value || [];
      const secondValue: string[] = frm.get('second').value || [];
      if (secondValue.length > 0 && firstValue.length > 0) {
        if (secondValue.some(v => firstValue.indexOf(v) !== -1)) {
          return { 'invalid': 'you can\'t use first element selection' }
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    this.form = fb.group({
      first: [],
      second: []
    }, { validator: dropDownValueValidation })
  }


  logValues() {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
```

> `dropDownValueValidation` function is the validation login for the dropdown values

*Template*

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="first" placeholder="Select Year/Week" class="DropDownYear" multiple >
        <mat-option *ngFor="let time1 of resYearData.time" [value]="time1">{{time1}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="second" placeholder="Select Year/Week" class="DropDownYear" multiple>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let time2 of resYearData.time" [value]="time2" >{{time2}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)='logValues()'>View</button>
</div>
<br>
Form Validation => {{form.errors | json}}
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53541202)